# Hive LLAP - ORC split generation failed

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, orc

I am trying to evaluate hive LLAP on a Hortonworks HDP 2.6 cluster.

Unfortunately, I get a **java.lang.RuntimeException: ORC split generation failed** when trying to execute queries:

```
ERROR : Status: Failed
ERROR : Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1504166274656_0006_3_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1504166274656_0006_3_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: gprs_records initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1504166274656_0006_3_00 [Map 1], java.lang.RuntimeException: ORC split generation failed with exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1615)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getSplits(OrcInputFormat.java:1701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.addSplitsForGroup(HiveInputFormat.java:446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.initialize(HiveSplitGenerator.java:196)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:278)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:269)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:269)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:253)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1609)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at org.apache.orc.OrcFile$WriterVersion.from(OrcFile.java:145)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.OrcTail.getWriterVersion(OrcTail.java:73)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.ReaderImpl.<init>(ReaderImpl.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.ReaderImpl.<init>(ReaderImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile.createReader(OrcFile.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.populateAndCacheStripeDetails(OrcInputFormat.java:1419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.callInternal(OrcInputFormat.java:1305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.access$2600(OrcInputFormat.java:1104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator$1.run(OrcInputFormat.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator$1.run(OrcInputFormat.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.call(OrcInputFormat.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.call(OrcInputFormat.java:1104)
    ... 4 more
]
ERROR : Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1504166274656_0006_3_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in INITED state., Vertex vertex_1504166274656_0006_3_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
ERROR : DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
INFO  : org.apache.tez.common.counters.DAGCounter:
INFO  :    AM_CPU_MILLISECONDS: 840
INFO  :    AM_GC_TIME_MILLIS: 23
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1504166274656_0006_3_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1504166274656_0006_3_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: gprs_records initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1504166274656_0006_3_00 [Map 1], java.lang.RuntimeException: ORC split generation failed with exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1615)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getSplits(OrcInputFormat.java:1701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.addSplitsForGroup(HiveInputFormat.java:446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.initialize(HiveSplitGenerator.java:196)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:278)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:269)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:269)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:253)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1609)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at org.apache.orc.OrcFile$WriterVersion.from(OrcFile.java:145)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.OrcTail.getWriterVersion(OrcTail.java:73)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.ReaderImpl.<init>(ReaderImpl.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.ReaderImpl.<init>(ReaderImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile.createReader(OrcFile.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.populateAndCacheStripeDetails(OrcInputFormat.java:1419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.callInternal(OrcInputFormat.java:1305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.access$2600(OrcInputFormat.java:1104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator$1.run(OrcInputFormat.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator$1.run(OrcInputFormat.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.call(OrcInputFormat.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.call(OrcInputFormat.java:1104)
    ... 4 more
]Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1504166274656_0006_3_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in INITED state., Vertex vertex_1504166274656_0006_3_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
INFO  : Resetting the caller context to HIVE_SSN_ID:2415846c-fb92-480f-b869-240a0b0f30ed
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20170831085623_51baf1df-5823-459e-80cf-76fa1f81789f); Time taken: 0.342 seconds
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1504166274656_0006_3_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1504166274656_0006_3_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: gprs_records initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1504166274656_0006_3_00 [Map 1], java.lang.RuntimeException: ORC split generation failed with exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1615)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getSplits(OrcInputFormat.java:1701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.addSplitsForGroup(HiveInputFormat.java:446)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.initialize(HiveSplitGenerator.java:196)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:278)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:269)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:269)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:253)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.generateSplitsInfo(OrcInputFormat.java:1609)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at org.apache.orc.OrcFile$WriterVersion.from(OrcFile.java:145)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.OrcTail.getWriterVersion(OrcTail.java:73)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.ReaderImpl.<init>(ReaderImpl.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.ReaderImpl.<init>(ReaderImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcFile.createReader(OrcFile.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.populateAndCacheStripeDetails(OrcInputFormat.java:1419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.callInternal(OrcInputFormat.java:1305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.access$2600(OrcInputFormat.java:1104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator$1.run(OrcInputFormat.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator$1.run(OrcInputFormat.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.call(OrcInputFormat.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$SplitGenerator.call(OrcInputFormat.java:1104)
    ... 4 more
]Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1504166274656_0006_3_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in INITED state., Vertex vertex_1504166274656_0006_3_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1 (state=08S01,code=2)
```

Here's some information to complete the picture:

- I've enabled LLAP using the Ambari interface, installed HiveServer interactive, restarted the services. I am using **Beeline version 1.2.1000.2.6.0** to connect to it.
- The table being queried is in **ORC format**. ORC files are generated by an ETL pipeline and written by Java code using [ORC Core](https://orc.apache.org/docs/core-java.html). I have no problem querying it without LLAP using HiveServer2.

Any advice is really appreciated. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to several known issues of ORC split generation. Try running the query with the following config:

hive.exec.orc.split.strategy=BI

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/131609/hive-llap-orc-split-generation-failed.html

Answer (score 0):

Your orc file is written by OrcFileWriter with larger version.
Is your hive's version 2.1.1?
1. Fix the problem by using this patch file. 
https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/apache/orc/pull/75.patch
2. Recompile the hive project. 
3. Replace the hive-exec-2.1.1.jar and hive-orc-2.1.1.jar in the lib directory.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help pages, take the SO tour, read How to Ask. Lastly please edit your question to include the programming language as a tag.